# correct sql query to simplify relationship (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

table A

```
id emp emp_dst
1   a    b
2   a    d
3   b    c
4   b    a
5   c    d
6   d    a
7   d    b
8   d    c
```

my sql query should return me the following simplified table since a = b equals b = a

table B

```
emp emp_dst
 a     b
 a     d
 b     c
 d     b
 d     c
```

but I have no idea how to do this in an sql query in MYSQL,

try revising expressions with UNION but the results are wrong

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of `id` in the result set

Comment: Figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Some answer that work for MySQL won't work for SQL-Server, and vice-versa.

Comment: I'm sorry to forget that I'm working on mysql

Comment: @jhoss - and as mentioned by Strawberry - The IDs in your example results don't match the IDs in the input data.  Do they matter?  What is their significance?

Comment: i the id does not have any relevance only I put it as an example

Comment: how come `d - b` is part of result, there is no `b - d` ?

Comment: yes, it's part of the result because d-b equals b-d

Comment: but there is no `b - d` in `tableA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative that suits my personal preferences better...

*(Based on your comment that the `id` in the results was not relevant.)*

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN emp <= emp_dst THEN emp     ELSE emp_dst END   AS emp,
  CASE WHEN emp <= emp_dst THEN emp_dst ELSE emp     END   AS emp_dst
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  1, 2
ORDER BY
  1, 2
```

If you want ***an*** `id`, then you can add `MIN(id)`.  Just note that the `id` found may actually have the two values the other way around.

An alternative that uses a `LEFT JOIN` rather than `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM
  yourTable
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable   AS reflection
    ON  reflection.emp_dst = yourTable.emp
    AND reflection.emp     = yourTable.emp_dst
    AND reflection.id     <> yourTable.id
WHERE
      (reflection.id IS NULL)
  OR  (yourTable.emp <  reflection.emp_dst)
  OR  (yourTable.emp =  reflection.emp_dst AND yourTable.id < reflection.id)
ORDER BY
  yourTable.emp,
  yourTable.emp_dst
```

*(The last `OR` is only needed if a table can have `'a', 'a'`, and it appear twice.)*

Note: This may benefit from having two indexes...

```
CREATE INDEX yourTable_e_ed_id ON yourTable( emp, emp_dst, id );
CREATE INDEX yourTable_ed_e_id ON yourTable( emp_dst, emp, id );
```

Comment: I am ideologically opposed to this solution

Comment: thank you but the previous answer seemed more general since I have a table with many records and I have to generalize this answer

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm always happy to hear opinions, but could you elaborate somewhat?  What about it are you opposed to, and what is your alternative?

Comment: @jhoss You may prefer a `WITH TIES` approach, but it doesn't exist in MySQL...  Also, this will work for many rows...

Comment: It is inappropriate to use a GROUP BY clause in the absence of any aggregating functions. My alternative would be subject to the OPs response to my earlier comments.

Comment: @Strawberry - Why is it inappropriate?  It has the same functionality as `DISTINCT`, but with the benefit of being adaptable to adding `MIN(id)`, etc.